# Why do the Shenzhou seating assignments differ from Soyuz?

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft, shenzhou

The [Shenzhou spacecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shenzhou_(spacecraft)) is China's crewed space vehicle.  It is derived from the Russian [Soyuz spacecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_spacecraft).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shenzou#Comparison_with_Soyuz),

> The commander sits in the center seat on both spacecraft. However, the copilot sits in the left seat on Shenzhou and the right seat on Soyuz.

Given the derivation of Shenzhou from Soyuz, **why are the seating assignments for the copilot and third crewmember different between these two spacecraft?**

Comment: "Derived", while used on the Shenzhou wikipedia page, is a little stronger term than I would use for the relationship between the two. Shenzhou borrowed the three-module Soyuz concept and some technology, but it's not a modified copy. See [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20070408034953/http://cns.miis.edu/pubs/week/031006.htm) for some of the differences.